# Integration Test for non web Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

**Description**
I have a spring boot application which is a non web application. It is a scheduled job, so it runs periodically to check an Amazon SQS queue. If there is a message, I proceed with the job provided by the parameters in the message

**Actual Problem**
I'm trying to run integration tests using maven.
I have an integration profile in pom.xml which will run only integration tests

```
mvn verify -Pintegration
```

**application-test.yml**

```
spring.datasource:
  url: ${DBCONNECTIONSTRING}
  type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
```

where DBCONNECTIONSTRING is my sql connection string which has username and password. It is an environment variable. Also, DBCONNECTIONSTRING points to the live db. I need to verify whether the data is updated or not.

**IntegrationTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = *****(SpringApplication).class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class IntegrationTest {

  @Autowired
  DependencyCheckService dependencyCheckService;

  @Test()
  public void integration() {
    Assert.assertTrue(dependencyCheckService.dbcheck());
  }
}
```

DependencyCheckImpl.java

```
@Service
public class DependencyCheckServiceImpl implements DependencyCheckService {

  @Autowired
  JdbcTemplate template;

  public boolean dbCheck() {
    try {
      List<Object> results = template.query("select 1 from dual", new SingleColumnRowMapper<>());
      if (results.size() == 1) {
        return true;
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      if (LOGGER.isErrorEnabled()) {
        LOGGER.error("Error when accessing database. " + e.getMessage());
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

When I run it on Docker. I get the following error

```
[ERROR] integration(com.bt.package.name.integrationtests.IntegrationTest)  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong with the configuration?
[EDIT] DBCONNECTIONSTRING actually starts with jdbc. It is in my environment variables. Could there be a reason why the test yml is not reading it properly from the env?

Comment: DBCONNECTIONSTRING must start with 'jdbc:'

Comment: DBCONNECTIONSTRING does start with jdbc. It's in the environment variables.
The spring application runs without any issues.